# Google chrome showing basic outdated color picker for <input type="color">

Tags: javascript, html

[This is the outdated color picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx8G7.png) 
[image]

[The color picker I want is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKj5x.png)
[image]

os -windows 10,
chrome vr -Latest version... I want to use different color picker which gives values dynamically.

My code :

```
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
var css = document.querySelector("h3");

function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = 
    "linear-gradient(to right, " 
    + color1.value 
    + ", " 
    + color2.value 
    + ")";

    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";" ;
}

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Background gradient</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">
     <h1>Background Generator</h1>
     <input class="color1" type="color" value="#ff0000">
     <input class="color2" type="color" value="#ffff00">
     <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
     <h3>linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0));</h3>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the second screenshot from a Mac?  Looks like it's just using the standard operating system one.  If you want something custom that's consistent for all users, you'll need to build it into your site itself.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, its from mac...ok got it...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can not style default color picker. There is option to install jQuery plugins and use their versions.

Here are some examples: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/color%20picker/